# Suppose $f \in L_+^1$ let $g(x,y)= \min(f(x), f(y))$. Is $g\in L_{+}^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, lp-spaces

Consider a function $f \ge 0$ such that $\int f(x) dx <\infty$.  Now let
$$g(x,y)= \min(f(x),   f(y)).$$

**Question:** Can we show that $$\int \int g(x,y) dx dy <\infty$$?  Or is there a counter-example?

I tried playing with examples but really could find anything. My intuition tells me that to find a counter-example somehow we have to make the function $g$ blow up really fast around zero.

Comment: I think the issue is in the decay of $f$. Haven't checked all the details, but an idea is to note that $\{ (x,y): g(x,y)>r\}= \{ x: f(x)>r\}\times\{ y: f(y)>r\}$, so we have $|\{ g(x,y)>r\}| = |\{ f(x)>r\}|^2$. The issue is that you can find $f\in L^1_+$ with $\int_0^1 |\{ f(x)>r\}|^2 \, dr =\infty$ (power functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I think work, with appropriate cut-offs).

Comment: BTW, I think the result is true in a finite measure space.

Comment: @Jose27  Thanks. Let me know if you figure it out.  I am interested in the Lebesugue measure over $\mathbb{R}$, but it will be interesting to see how it work for finite-dimensional setting too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this counterexample:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}\chi_{[1,\infty)}\in L^1_+,$ and for $0<x<y\implies f(x)>f(y)$

so defining the set $D:=\{(x,y)|y>x>1\}$ we have $g(x,y)_{|D}=\frac{1}{y^2}$:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|g|\geq \int_{D}|g|= \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty
}\int_1^R \text dx\int_x^R \text dy \frac{1}{y^2} =\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty
}\int_1^R \text dx \left[\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{R}\right]=\infty $$

Comment: Thanks. Looks correct to me.